# Looping never happens while the condition is never being satisfied?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arguments, conditional-statements

### Thanks for 000 suggested ans, but im still a newbie, would like to know the concept behind this result.         Anyone can make explicit?

```
0hi
3hello
3world
```

instead of

```
0hi
0hello
0world
```

(assumption: `num` is never be `++` as the value is `0`.)

```
application.args=hi hello world

public static void main (String[] args){
    int num;
    num=0;

    for (String s:args) {
        System.out.println(num+s);
        for(num=0;2>=num;num++);
    }

}
```

Comment: ehm, what do you think you do here: for(num=0;2>=num;num++); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print all arguments and number with it then modify your loop like

```
for (String s:args){
System.out.println(num + " " + s);
num++;  // don't write this if you want 0 as the number every time
}
```

**Edit**
If you want to know why num in your code is incremented to 3 then

- the control first come to `for(String s: args)`
- Then it copies first value (value at 0 index) of args into s
- Then it hits `System.out.println(num+s);` which print value of num which is still zero and value of s
- Now `for(num=0;2>=num;num++);` it will increment num until `num ≤= 2` so after the for statement execute your num value becomes 3
- Then it goes for second iteration of outer loop copies second value of args into s
- Then print num(which is 3) along with s and this will be repeated until all values in args are not processed

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, As you want the output: 0hi 0hello 0world

```
    int num = 0;
    for (String s : args) {
        //To get array of words data[0] = "hi", data[1] = "hello", data[2] = "world"
        String[] data = s.split(" ");
        //Loop through all words
        for (String element : data) {
            System.out.println(num + element);
        }
    }
```